# I need to get the output as html table format using python

Tags: python, html

Please find my code and output below to convert as a html table format.

```
cmd = "ls -Altr hpsm_%s.* | tail -n -1 | awk '{print $6,$7,$8,$9'}" % i
output1 = [commands.getoutput(cmd).split("\n")]
print(output1)
```

output:
Output type list need to get it in html table format

```
[['Dec 1 03:18 hpsm_tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline.log']]
[['ls: cannot access hpsm_tAlert_K8s_kubernetes_health_by_POD.*: No such file or directory']]
[['Dec 29 03:42 hpsm_tAlert_NN_WMS_endpoint-message-count_MSE.log']]
[['Nov 24 03:48 hpsm_tAlert_NN_ecom_version_check.log']]
[['Nov 24 03:48 hpsm_tAlert_NN_ecom_version_check_all_farms.log']]
[['Jan 3 03:55 hpsm_tAlert_NN_metrics_fileSystem.log']]
```

Expected output

```
Alert Name                           | status time

tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline.log    | Dec 1 03:18

tAlert_K8s_kubernetes_health_by_POD  | NA
```

Below is the code i have tried so far

```
def validate(date_text):
  try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%b %d %H:%M')
    return date_text
  except Exception:
    return 'NA'

for i in outputlist:

  cmd = "ls -Altr hpsm_%s.* | tail -n -1 | awk '{print $6,$7,$8,$9'}" % i
  output1 = [commands.getoutput(cmd).split("\n")]



  new_arr = list()
  for out in output1:

      for new_out in out:
          temp_arr = new_out.split("hpsm_")
          temp_arr[0] = validate(temp_arr[0])
          new_arr.append(temp_arr)
  print(new_arr)
```

Comment: The output array format you have shown is incorrect. You may want to revisit the exact output you are getting.

Comment: No the `output1` what you have printed is incorrect. Please look at what exactly is being printed by `print(output1) `

Comment: here  the output is dynamically stored it to "output1". Exactly it stores the last modification of the time and the filename

Comment: Like this only [['Dec 1 03:18 hpsm_tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline.log']] i am getting the output while printing "output1"' and the output1 type is "List"

Comment: While trying the below code i am getting the output as                                    
[['NA', 'tAlert_ALL_circuit-breaker.log_301219']]
[['NA', 'tAlert_ALL_load5_hqchnesoanfs.*: No such file or directory']]
[['NA', 'tAlert_ALL_metrics_cpu.log']]
[['NA', 'tAlert_ALL_metrics_memory_usage.log']]
[['NA', 'tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline.log']]
[['NA', 'tAlert_K8s_kubernetes_health_by_POD.*: No such file or directory']]
[['NA', 'tAlert_NN_WMS_endpoint-message-count_MSE.log']]

Comment: For all the values its giving "NA" only

Comment: The code is written taking `output1` into account. Please modify the code as per your requirement. I do not have access to your environment and the people here are not there to work for you. We can provide you guidance, writing the exact algorithm is your task.

Comment: Actually i have changed the below code as per my requirement. after that only i got the mentioned output

Comment: Please update your question with code and try to figure out why `NA` is showing up. There is just one method that can return `NA`.

Comment: Please check what error you are getting in `validatetext` method. The date is not getting converted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code using `pandas`

```py
output1 = [['Dec 1 03:18 hpsm_tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline.log']]
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%b %d %H:%M')
        return date_text
    except Exception:
        return 'NA'

new_arr = list()
for out in output1:
    for new_out in out:
        temp_arr = new_out.split(" hpsm_")
        temp_arr[0] = validate(temp_arr[0])
        new_arr.append(temp_arr)
print(new_arr)
df = pd.DataFrame(new_arr, columns = ['Alert Name', 'Status Time'])
print(df)

#output
    Alert Name                        Status Time
0  Dec 1 03:18  tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline.log
```